# Top N not working with Stream Analytics job

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I am new to Power BI and Stream Analytics job.

I am trying to get the latest/recent value in Power BI based on timestamp. I Pushed the data from Stream Analytics job to Power BI dataset. I am receiving all the data successfully.

Now for one particular instance I want to show latest value from Stream Analytics job. I used simple matrix/Table to display the data. It display the data correctly. However when I try to use the Top N with N=1 it returns null. The same thing used to work correctly when I pulled the data from Azure Tables.

I just want to display the recent data (single value) from Steam to Power BI. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Regards,

AJ

[image]

Comment: We could not help you without your example data and ASA query.

Comment: The Azure Analyser Job Query is simple:SELECT
    *
INTO
    strPowerBi2
FROM
    strInputs

Comment: The Azure Analyser Job Query is simple:

SELECT
    *
INTO
    strPowerBi2
FROM
    strInputs

strInput is linked to iot hub and strPowerBi2 is linked to dataset in Power BI. the data is sending through a code 

Bote that I am able to get the data in Power BI however it does not filter based on Top N. it returns blank records. Instead if i use the Azure Table the Power BI works ok. But That's I want to get it work wth Azure Stream Analystics job.

Data stream from the device as below:using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;